# Break a WordPress post on paragraph tags

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I have a site with two databases. One is attached to the WordPress install that runs part of the content of the site; the other runs the site overall. Let's call them cwordpress and tdasite.

I have figured out how to access the WordPress database and pull content from it, but I'm not sure how to break it down on the p tags, because I'm pulling the post_content file.  I need to display the text in a sidebar, and for readability, it's nice to have it in actual paragraphs. The articles I'm pulling from are generally very short, but there are three to five paragraphs in each.

I'm not seeing how WordPress saves the formatting. It clearly does, since the WordPress pages display appropriately, and the tags show up in View Source, but they're not visible in the database. Otherwise, I'd use explode to break them into paragraphs and display them that way. But so far, I can't even turn the post_content object into a variable and print it! Is what I'm trying to do possible, or do I need to concept?

This is the query code.

```
<?php
//Connect to WordPress database
$dbc = mysqli_connect(DATABASE CREDENTIALS) or die('Error connecting to MySQL server.');

//Define the query to retrieve international news posts 
$newsquery = 'SELECT wp_posts.post_title, wp_posts.ID, wp_posts.post_content FROM wp_posts, wp_term_relationships, wp_term_taxonomy WHERE wp_posts.ID=wp_term_relationships.object_id AND wp_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id=wp_term_taxonomy.term_taxonomy_id AND wp_term_taxonomy.taxonomy="category" AND wp_term_taxonomy.term_id=5 ORDER BY wp_posts.post_date DESC LIMIT 1';

if($r = mysqli_query($dbc, $newsquery)) { // Run the query.
   while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($r)) {
      echo '<h3 class="betterheader" align="center">' . $row['post_title'] . '</h3><p class="sidebartext">' . $row['post_content'] . '</p>';
   }
} else { 
   echo '<p style="color: red;">No international news today!</p>';
}
?>
```

That will return my post as a giant block of text, but when I try to declare post_content as a variable and then display it, nothing turns up, which makes me think I can't handle the post the way I want to.  And for reference, this is all I was doing for that:

```
$wppost = $row['post_title'];
echo $wppost
```

Comment: Learn about explicit `JOIN`s

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question (*what I'm trying to do possible, or do I need to reconcept?*), sir the html tags are defined in the page/post templates, and thus  are usually not included in the database values.

My suggestion would be install a Wordpress php-executor plugin that will work for sidebar widgets, then create a text widget and put your php code-for-content there. I suggest using the built-in functions like get_the_title and get_the_content, and just apply the proper arguments if you want it them to be dynamic.

Comment: I'll look into this. As I read your comment, I thought "I bet there is a plugin." My only concern with that is that the sidebar is outside of the Wordpress files, but even then, this cannot be the first time someone's needed to do this sort of thing.  Thanks!

Comment: The sidebar is actually inside Wordpress, in the current theme's files. This is named sidebar.php, which you then produce in any page via the function get_sidebar().

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php query_posts('showposts'); while(have_posts()): the_post();  the_title  the_content  endwhile; wp_reset_query(); ?>
```

try this one it will help you